# How can I get the average of the elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, iteration, nested-lists

I am trying to iterate over a nested list in Python and calculate the average of the elements in each inner list. Here is an example of the nested list I am working with:

```py
student_marks = [
    ['Name', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']],
    ['Shiloh', [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
    ['Shawn', [42, 23, 34, 42, 53]],
    ['Lewis', [32, 23, 23, 54, 67]],
    ['Pete', [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
    ['Rock', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
]
```

I attempted to calculate the average by summing up the elements and dividing by the length of the inner list, but I encountered an error stating that the integer object is not iterable. Here is my code:

```py
for i in student_marks[1:]:
    marks_in_C = i[1][2]
    print(marks_in_C)

    average = sum(marks_in_C) / len(marks_in_C)
    print(average)
```

Comment: Hi -Welcome to SO. you can either write another for loop to calculate the sum of the inner list, or use some packages like [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to convert it to a ```np.array``` and then you can use ```sum``` directly.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? Why are there five answers?

Comment: Use `i[1]` instead of `i[1][2]`.  Inside your loop, `i` already contains an individual row (e.g. `['Shiloh', [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]]`)  so, item `1` of that is the list of values on which to do the average.

Answer (score 2):

If the values you're trying to manipulate are always in that last cell of the nested loops, something like this would work:

```
for student_value in student_marks:
    name  = student_value[0]
    marks = student_value[1]
    avg_score = sum(marks)/len(marks)
    print(f"{name}'s avg score is {avg_score}")
```

Comment: You could take this a step further and make a record of everyone's score as a dictionary (suppose we call it report = {}) and on each iteration cast to it with report[name] = avg_score, that way all scores are 'searchable' in the dict by name

Comment: A more idiomatic way would be `for name, mark in student_marks:`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
student_marks = [['Name', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']],
                 ['Shiloh', [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
                 ['Shawn', [42, 23, 34, 42, 53]],
                 ['Lewis', [32, 23, 23, 54, 67]],
                 ['Pete', [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
                 ['Rock', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
                ]

s = [ i[1][2] for i in student_marks[1:]]
print(sum(s)/len(s))
```

You can use *list comprehension* (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list with just the elements you want. In this example, I extract just the 'C' column from the records, into a new list called 's', then I just get the average with `sum` and `len`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a good idea to develop a more generalised solution whereby you get the average by subject (e.g., C) rather than using constant indexes.

Something like this:

```
student_marks = [['Name', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']],
                 ['Shiloh', [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
                 ['Shawn', [42, 23, 34, 42, 53]],
                 ['Lewis', [32, 23, 23, 54, 67]],
                 ['Pete', [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
                 ['Rock', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
                ]

def get_average_by_subject(table, subject):
    try:
        index = table[0][1].index(subject)
        values = [scores[index] for _, scores in table[1:]]
        return sum(values) / len(values)
    except Exception:
        pass
    
print(get_average_by_subject(student_marks, 'C'))
```

**Output:**

```
30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently storing only one value at a time in the marks_in_C variable. Try putting them in a list and then performing your operations on the list after running the loop.

```
marks_in_C = []
for i in student_marks[1:]:
    marks_in_C.append(i[1][2])
    
print (marks_in_C)
```

This will work now as you expect:

```
average = sum (marks_in_C)/ len(marks_in_C)
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
student_marks = [['Name', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']],
                 ['Shiloh', [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
                 ['Shawn', [42, 23, 34, 42, 53]],
                 ['Lewis', [32, 23, 23, 54, 67]],
                 ['Pete', [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
                 ['Rock', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
                ]

student_marks.pop(0)

for i in student_marks:
    avg_marks = sum(i[1]) / len(i[1])
    print(avg_marks)
```

This would seem to be what you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).